# Expectation of $x^4$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Can anyone help me prove that Expected Value of $X^4$ is $3\,($Var$(X))^4$, if the Expected Value of $X$ is zero and Var$(X)$ is the Variance of $X$ $(N(0,\sigma^2))$.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I want to prove it by expected value(first moment) formula . so E(x^4)= integral x^4 f(x) dx   , but how can I solve it?!

Comment: Integration by parts from the integral expression of $E(X^2)$ (you differentiate the exponential)

Answer (score 5):

**HINT :**

We know that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\Large-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dx=1,\tag1
$$

$$
\text{E}[X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\Large-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dx=\mu,\tag2
$$
and
$$
\text{E}\left[X^2\right]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\Large-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dx=\text{Var}[X]+(\text{E}[X])^2=\sigma^2+\mu^2.\tag3
$$
Then differentiate $(3)$ with respect to $\mu$ twice.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2}\left(\frac{x^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\Large-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\ dx=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2}\left(\sigma^2+\mu^2\right).\tag4
$$
Using $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, and $\mu=0$, we can obtain the following result
$$
\text{E}\left[X^4\right]=3\left(\text{Var}[X]\right)^2.  =3*\sigma^4    
$$

Comment: :I follow your hint. the simplifiy of left hand side of (4) is  -1+ E(x^4)/ sigma^4 . and right hand side of (4) is : 1+∂2∂μ2(σ2) . but now what should I do !?

Comment: @user3140486 First we process
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}\left(\frac{x^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{\Large-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\ dx=\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}\left(\sigma^2+\mu^2\right)
$$
to obtain $\text{E}[X^3]$. After that, you process $(4)$ to obtain the $\text{E}[X^4]=3\sigma^8$.

Comment: @user3140486 Easier way, you can use the property of [Gaussian integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html). Click the given link and see equation $(34)$.

Comment: I've done these steps. myy question is that what should I put instead of the second derivative of sigma^2 respect ro mo^2    =>    ∂2∂μ2(σ2)   is it equal to 1 !!!??