# How to prove that $E[||\mathbf x||^4]=K(K+1)$? where $K$ is the length of $\mathbf x$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Let $\mathbf x=[x_1, ... ,x_K]^T$, $x\sim\mathcal C\mathcal N(\mathbf 0,\sigma_x^2\mathbf I)$, I have worked out the value of $E[||\mathbf x||^4]$ by assuming values for the vector $\mathbf x$ and found it was $K(K+1)$ when $\sigma_x^2=1$. Can I prove it in the same manner as the answer in [Expectation of $x^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792189/expectation-of-x4). 
Also, what is the above expectation when $\sigma_x^2\ne 1$? What is $E[||\mathbf x||^8]$?

Comment: What is $|x|$? Is it $L_2$-norm?

Comment: @d.k.o. $|\mathbf x|=\sqrt{\mathbf x^H\mathbf x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_i=\operatorname{re}(x_i)$ and $z_i=\operatorname{im}(x_i)$. Then, for $\sigma_x=1$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}|\mathbf{x}|^4&=\mathsf{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^K (y_i^2+z_i^2)\right)^2 \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^K\mathsf{E}(y_i^2+z_i^2)^2+\sum_{i=1}^K\sum_{j\ne i}\mathsf{E}(y_i^2+z_i^2)(y_j^2+z_j^2) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^K(\mathsf{E}y_i^4+\mathsf{E}z_i^4+2\mathsf{E}y_i^2\mathsf{E}z_i^2)+\sum_{i=1}^K\sum_{j\ne i}\mathsf{E}(y_i^2+z_i^2)\mathsf{E}(y_j^2+z_j^2) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^K 8\cdot2^{-2}+\sum_{i=1}^K\sum_{j\ne i}4 \cdot 2^{-2}=K(K+1).
\end{align}

For $\sigma_x\ne 1$, note that $\mathbf{x}/\sigma_x\sim \mathcal{CN}(0,I)$.

Comment: Thank you d.k.o. Just wondering why you've got different answer than @P.Quinton answer. I've been trying to guess why.

Comment: $\bar{x_i}x_i=|x_i|^2\ne x_i^2$.

Comment: how is that related to my question?

Comment: The first line is incorrect. So why bothering to follow the rest?

Comment: Cool. How about $E[|\mathbf x|^8]$. I've tried but it requires $E[|x_i|^6]$ and $E[|x_i|^8]$. Any idea?

Comment: You need to apply [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Theorem) to expand $(\sum \cdot)^3$ and $(\sum \cdot)^4$. Simple but tedious.

Comment: I don't understand your first step. Shouldn't you just have $$E |x|^4 = E \Big(\sum_i (y_i^2 + z_i^2)\Big)^2$$ without the second sum that you write down?

Comment: Thank you @d.k.o. However, even with the link you provided, still I need to know $E[|x_i|^6]$ and $E[|x_i|^8]$. Note that $x_i$ is a complex number not a vector.