# Finding Expected Value of X^4 where X is a standard normal distribution

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand how to prove that $\mathbb{E}$[$X^4_i$]=3 using integration by parts, where $X_i$ ~ $N(0,1)$. I've tried to interpret it as $\mathbb{E}$[$(X^2_i)^2$], so that I can find it using change-of-variable formula:

$\mathbb{E}$[$X^4_i$] = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f_{x^2_i}(x)dx$

Where I use $f_{x^2_i}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_{x^2_i}(x)$ by finding $F_{x^2_i}(x)$= $\int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}x^2f_{x_i}(x)dx$ = $2F_{x_i}(\sqrt{x})$

Thus, $\mathbb{E}$[$X^4_i$] = $\int_{0}^{\infty}2x^2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$)dx

I've tried using integration by parts following this, but I did not end up with 3 as my answer.

Another approach I tried to take was to use $\mathbb{E}$[$X^4_i$] = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^4f_{x_i}(x)dx$, which I thought could be more promising, but I did not know how to integrate this without using the erf function, which I have not learned yet.

If it is poor integration on my part, I apologize, but I just don't know if my approach is correct in the first place, and if not, what the right way to solve a question like this would be.

Here are some things that have my scratching my head a little:

1. Is it correct to assume that in my first approach I can set the integral to go from 0 to $\infty$ since x≥0?
2. How would one get rid of the π to end up with a clean number like 3? I'm sure the correct solution would show this clearly, but I just cannot understand how that would happen conceptually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you! I know a similar question has been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792189/expectation-of-x4), but it didn't use integration by parts and I couldn't figure out how to incorporate it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is an error in your computation.  Note the $i$ subscript is irrelevant; we are considering only one standard normal variable, which we will denote $X$.  Then the transformed variable $Y = g(X) = X^2$ has density
$$f_Y(y) = 2f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy}\right| = \frac{f_X(\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{y}} = \frac{e^{-y/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{y}}, \quad y > 0.$$  The extra factor of $2$ in the formula is a consequence of the two-to-one mapping of $g$, i.e. $g(-X) = g(X)$.  You could also perform the computation in the traditional manner with the normal CDF as you proposed, but what you are missing is the factor of $1/\sqrt{y}$.

Consequently,
$$\operatorname{E}[X^4] = \operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \int_{y=0}^\infty y^2 f_Y(y) \, dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{y=0}^\infty y^{3/2} e^{-y/2} \, dy.$$  This is, after substitution of the form $t = y/2$, a gamma function integral.

However, this initial transformation is unnecessary.  For the fourth moment, it is more elementary to just do the calculation via integration by parts.  Explicitly,

$$\operatorname{E}[X^4] = 2\int_{x=0}^\infty x^4 f_X(x) \, dx,$$ and with the choice $$ u = x^3, \quad du = 3x^2 \, dx, \\ dv = x f_X(x) \, dx, \quad v = -f_X(x),$$ we obtain
$$\operatorname{E}[X^4] = \left[ -2x^3 f_X(x) \right]_{x=0}^\infty + 6 \int_{x=0}^\infty x^2 f_X(x) \, dx = 6 \int_{x=0}^\infty x^2 f_X(x) \, dx.$$

Repeating the process again with the choice
$$u = x, \quad du = dx, \\ dv = x f_X(x) \, dx, \quad v = -f_X(x),$$ and noting the $uv$ term again vanishes,

$$\operatorname{E}[X^4] = 6 \int_{x=0}^\infty f_X(x) \, dx = 3.$$

Comment: Thank you so much @heropup for the detailed explanation, I'm very grateful. Just to make sure I'm understanding the last step correctly, $\int_{x=0}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx$ = 1/2 because it is half of the normal distribution, which has a total area of 1, right?

Comment: @jasonL Correct.  The integral of the standard normal density from 0 to infinity is simply $1/2$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand how $v = -f_X(x)$ was determined from $dv = xf_X(x)dx$, could you please explain? I know this is probably quite basic but I can't seem to figure out how to integrate $dv$ correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @jasonL Observe that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{-x^2/2}\right] = -x e^{-x^2/2},$$ hence if $v = - f_X(x)$, then $dv/dx = x f_X(x).$