# Expected Value of $X^4$ if $X$ ~$N(0, \sigma^2 )$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Can anyone help me prove that Expected Value of $X^4$ is $3 \sigma^4$ if $X$ is normally distributed with zero expected value and variance equals $\sigma^2$?

I have tried to derive by myself using the hints in this post [Expectation of $x^4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792189/expectation-of-x4) but I haven't made any progress.

Comment: Can you point out exactly what about the linked solution isn't clear? Or share what steps you took in your attempted derivation and where things seem to go wrong?

Comment: I don't get the step (4). Why we diferentiate the expected value of $X^2$ with respect to $\mu$?

Comment: It is well known that a standard gaussian has second cumulant 1, and all other cumulants 0. In particular, the fourth moment is equal to three times the square of the second moment.

Comment: By scaling you can assume $\sigma = 1$. It's easy to get all moments of $X ~ N(0, 1)$ by expanding the mgf $\phi(t) = E(e^{tX}) = e^{t^2 / 2}$ as a Taylor series around $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating w.r.t. $\mu$ any number of times preserves the exponential factor, so that the integral can be expressed as a linear combination of expectations:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2} \frac{x^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\tfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} &= \frac{x^4 - 2\mu x^3+\left(\mu^2-\sigma^2\right)x^2}{\sigma^5 \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\tfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \\
\implies \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\mu^2} \frac{x^2}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\tfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \,dx &= \frac1{\sigma^4} \Bbb E\left[X^4\right] - \frac{2\mu}{\sigma^4} \Bbb E\left[X^3\right] + \frac{\mu^2-\sigma^2}{\sigma^4} \Bbb E\left[X^2\right]
\end{align*}$$

Meanwhile, $\Bbb E\left[X^2\right]=\sigma^2+\mu^2$ so upon differentiating and plugging in $\mu=0$ we have the relation

$$2 = \frac1{\sigma^4} \Bbb E\left[X^4\right] - \frac1{\sigma^2} \Bbb E\left[X^2\right]$$

and the result follows.